# Disable mentions in say command (discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I wrote a simple "say" command, but I'm trying to **disable the mentioning** of any role and/or user.
For example, If someone types "!say @everyone", the bot instead of replying with "@everyone" and tagging everyone, should reply with "You don't have permission!" or just execute the user's command but filtering out the @ before "everyone".
Here's my code:

```
module.exports = {
  name: "say",
  description: "Say command",
  usage: "<msg>",
  run: async (bot, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.permissions.has("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return;
    let MSG = message.content.split(`${bot.prefix}say `).join("");
    if (!MSG)
      return message.channel.send(`Non hai specificato il messaggio da inviare!`);
    message.channel.send(MSG);
    message.delete();
  },
};
```

Can someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `allowedMentions` of `messageOptions` when sending the message

```js
// In discord.js V13, but this works on V12

message.channel.send({ content: "Hello @everyone", allowedMentions: { parse: [] }});
```

This will make the message output cleanly, the mention will still be seen as a mention **but will not mention anyone**.

Answer (score 2):

Or if you want to remove mentions from message then you can use RegExp:

```js
// If Message Content Includes Mentions
if (message.content.includes(/<@.?[0-9]*?>/g)) {
  //Replace All Message Mentions Into Nothing
  message = message.replace(/<@.?[0-9]*?>/g, "");
};
```

Explication:
we check if message content includes mention or not if yes then replace all mentions into nothing

Links:
[Learn About RegExp](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp)
[RegExp Source](https://www.regexpal.com/103473)

Answer (score -1):

Or.. just add this on client options: (i'll show full example)

```js
  const Discord = require('discord.js')
  const client = new Discord.Client({
  disableMentions: "everyone", //THIS 
  intents: [
    "GUILDS",
    "GUILD_MESSAGES",
    "GUILD_INTEGRATIONS",
    "GUILD_VOICE_STATES",
    "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS",
    "DIRECT_MESSAGES"
  ] //optional
});
```